# If f(n) = Θ(g(n)), is 2^f(n) = Θ(2^g(n))?

Tags: math, time-complexity, big-o

If f(n) is Θ(g(n)), then is the function 2<sup>f(n)</sup> is always Θ(2<sup>g(n)</sup>)? Why or why not?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question.  If it is, please tag it as such.  Also, tell us what progress you have made so far and where you are stuck.  SO is not here to do your homework for you, but we will provide help to posters who have made a valid effort on their own.

Comment: This question goes to your understanding of Θ. So, what is the definition of Θ? Think about which terms dominate and why.

Answer (score 4):

This statement is false. Take f(n) = 2n and g(n) = n. Then f(n) = Θ(g(n)) because 2n = Θ(n).

However, 2<sup>f(n)</sup> = 2<sup>2n</sup> = 4<sup>n</sup> and 2<sup>g(n)</sup> = 2<sup>n</sup>, but 4<sup>n</sup> ≠ Θ(2<sup>n</sup>). You can see this because

> lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> 4<sup>n</sup> / 2<sup>n</sup>
>
> = lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> 2<sup>n</sup>
>
> = ∞

Hope this helps!